# When a checkbox is unchecked, find all divs with matching class and remove them. JQUERY

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors

I want to run a function that removes a number of divs when a check box is unchecked. The divs contain a class that has to match with the check boxes class for it to be removed.

The variable `matchedDots` is getting the divs that match the variable class of `checkBoxID`.

`checkBoxID` is the class of the check box being unchecked.

```
       var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('class');

       var matchedDots = $('.current-map').find('div').hasClass(checkBoxID);

        if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            //do something
        };
```

So really what im trying to do is say "IF the check box is unchecked AND the div class matches up with the checkbox's class, do something.

I don't need the info of how to remove the divs, just how to select them, as currently all I'm selecting is the unchecked check box.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I have been confusing you guys but I have worked it out myself. Here is the code below. It was definitely easier than I thought it would be.

@Alex, thanks for your input though! really appreciated that.

```
        var checkBoxID = $(this).attr('class');

        if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {

            $('div.' + checkBoxID).hide();

        };
```

Basically I am getting the `class` from the check box. Then running an `IF` statement to see if the check box has been unchecked, if it has, I remove the `div`s with the same class as the check box.